# How to add 3rd party cpp library to android as dependency

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I have seen instructions for this if the 3rd party is using CMake(Google even has example for that https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-libs), yet my library is using **waf**. Thus, I am not sure how to do this.

I have also seen hacks that directly put dynamically linked library to the Android project. Yet I am concerned that the .so file I have is compiled under x86_64 and it won't be compatible for other architectures.

In all, I have googled two days and I haven't found a good way to import a 3rd party cpp source code to my Android project. Can anyone tell me what's the best way to do it?

Comment: I think you have (2) choices: (1) Configure the 3rd party build tools to use the Android standalone toolchain: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain or (2) Reverse engine the 3rd party build process and write a CMake script for Android.